# Converting a tab- and newline-delimited string into dataframe in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, type-conversion

I have a tab- and newline-delimited string which looks like this:

```
"From\tTo\nA0A3Q8IUE6\t13392634\nA4I9M8\t5072523\nE9BQL4\t13392634\nQ4Q3E9\t5654813\nE9B4M7\t13452251\n"
```

How do I convert this string into a dataframe consisting of two columns named 'From' and 'To' in R?

Comment: If that string is stored in a variable `x`, use `read.table(text=x, header=T)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `fread` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
fread(text = str1)
```

-output

```
    From       To
1: A0A3Q8IUE6 13392634
2:     A4I9M8  5072523
3:     E9BQL4 13392634
4:     Q4Q3E9  5654813
5:     E9B4M7 13452251
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use  `read_table2` from `readr` package

```
library(readr)
read_table2(
    "From\tTo\nA0A3Q8IUE6\t13392634\nA4I9M8\t5072523\nE9BQL4\t13392634\nQ4Q3E9\t5654813\nE9B4M7\t13452251\n"
    )
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  From             To
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 A0A3Q8IUE6 13392634
2 A4I9M8      5072523
3 E9BQL4     13392634
4 Q4Q3E9      5654813
5 E9B4M7     13452251
```